# How do I pass jvm arguments to the Jooq Code Generator when run from gradle?

Tags: gradle, jooq

With the release of Jooq version 3.14.0 there was a bit of code added to the org.jooq.codegen.GeneratorWriter class in an apparent response to an indentation issue:

```
 if (indentTabsAllLines < 0 && !Boolean.getBoolean("mute-indentation-error"))
            new IllegalStateException("A formatting error has been produced by https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10196").printStackTrace(System.err);
```

My gradle project is configured to use Jooq version 3.14.0, and the nu.studer.jooq plugin version 5.2.

During my code generation run, that code block is triggered many times and giving alarm during the build process when there isn't one.  The code that is generated compiles fine; this exception logging is a nuisance.

I want to run the code generator with that system property, but so far adding it to the gradle configuration isn't working.

Attempts so far:

- I've added it to the root project gradle.properties as "systemProp.mute-indentation-error"
- Added a separate task to the build.gradle file setting that system property prior to running jooqGenerate:

```
task setJooqGeneratorProperty () {
//    System.properties["mute-indentation-error"] = "true"
//    System.setProperty("systemProp.mute-indentation-error", "true");
//    systemProperty "mute-indentation-error", "true"
    println "ENV: " + System.properties
    println "Property[mute-indentation-error]: " + System.getProperty("mute-indentation-error")
}
...
generateJooq.dependsOn setJooqGeneratorProperty
```

None of which are setting that system property during the code generation.  I understand that the code generator is run in a different JVM with the Jooq plugin, but there doesn't seem to be anywhere to configure the JVM args for that JVM.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The underlying issue (I think) will be addressed soon. It's probably this one: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10782. If that's not it, it would also be interesting to report the issue you're having, and a means to reproduce the error, so the error can be fixed: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose. Also worth perhaps reporting an issue here, requesting a way to set or pass on system properties to the plugin: https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/issues/new